# babel-jest does not polyfill Array.flat

Tags: jestjs, vue-cli-3

I use `Array.flat()` in my Vue application and my tests fail with `TypeError: variable.flat is not a function`.

I already found some github issues but none could help:

[Link 1](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/issues/828)
[Link 2](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/3834)

Any ideas why babel does not polyfill the Array.flat function?

---

My configs (all located in the root directory)

.browserslistrc

```
defaults
```

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/app',
  ],
};
```

jest.config.js

```
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    'js',
    'jsx',
    'json',
    'vue',
  ],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.vue$': 'vue-jest',
    '.+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|svg|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$': 'jest-transform-stub',
    '^.+\\.jsx?$': 'babel-jest',
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '/node_modules/',
  ],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
  },
...
};

};
```

package.json

```
  "name": "bpceitenmanger",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@mdi/font": "^3.7.95",
    "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "date-fns": "^1.30.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-chartjs": "^3.4.2",
    "vue-clipboard2": "^0.3.0",
    "vue-i18n": "^8.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.3",
    "vuelidate": "^0.7.4",
    "vuetify": "^2.0.10",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "^3.11.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.5.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-airbnb": "^4.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "1.0.0-beta.29",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.18.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "stylus": "^0.54.5",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-cli-plugin-i18n": "^0.6.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^0.6.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.2.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stupid me!

A simple node update from v10.15.3 to v12.10.0 did the job.